# Issues importing tkinter on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'll preface this by saying that I am aware that on 2.7 it should be:

```
import Tkinter
```

However, for whatever reason on my desktop running xenial and

```
python --version
```

returning:

```
python 2.7.12
```

I have had no trouble throughout the development of an application on my system importing tkinter with

```
import tkinter
```

[image: 2.7 working with import tkinter]

I am wholly confused because as I went to work on a different machine I attempted to run my code only to find out I should have been using

```
import Tkinter
```

Which executes fine on the second machine. However,

```
import tkinter
```

returns that there is no module named tkinter.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: @Nae I do not have a local tkinter.py in the same directory, I have never used python 3, and as the screenshot shows above it will import tkinter in a 2.7 shell

Comment: I can reproduce your results, maybe take a look at the `tkinter` module it is importing, what does `print tkinter.__file__` output? On my system it points to a custom directory `/Users/davedwar/Software/tkinter/__init__.pyc`, whose source contains https://paste.pound-python.org/show/5wOrnFmUKORxGzK2zXjY/  which you can see handles the python2 `import Tkinter`. Maybe your system is doing similarly.

Comment: @davedwards

That printed out /usr/local/python2.7/dist-packages/tkinter/__init__.pyc 

I'm not really sure whats going on now hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have installed the `six` module at some point. It includes a dummy `tkinter` that allows python3 style tkinter imports in python2.

Comment: I don't remember doing so but you are correct! Thanks!

Comment: @FosterWilliams most likely you installed it indirectly, ie you installed a module that required `six`, so it was installed as well. It's pretty common since it saves people the work of writing separate python2 and python3 versions of a module.